# Move last element of vector<vector<int>> to beginning

Tags: c++, vector, std

I need to move last element of `vector<vector<int>>` to beginning. I tried `std::rotate` , but it works only on integers. Also i tried `std::move` but I failed. How I can do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "but it works only on integers" Why do you say that?

Comment: How about std::swap?

Comment: @0x499602D2 I read that on reddit, but now I can see it's not true. I'm trying to use it right now.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I must take the last element and put it to the beginning. I can't swap them because I can't mess up the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place the last element at the beginning you can utilize the [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) function with [reverse iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin). This performs a *right rotation*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());
    for (auto el : v) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
}
```

To swap the first and last element utilize the [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function with vector's [front()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front) and [back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) references:

```
std::swap(v.front(), v.back());
```

The `std::rotate` function is not dependent on the type.